# Should we sanitize $_FILES['filename']['name']?

Tags: php

After the user uploads an image to the server, should we sanitize `$_FILES['filename']['name']`?

I do check file size/file type etc. But I don't check other things. Is there a potential security hole?

Thank you

Comment: I would say that you probably want to name it instead of leaving your users to name it, for example if you save it to a database name the file the id or give it is own md5 as name ... that depends on how you doing it aswell but i would totally give it a md5 or checksum the file or something alike.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Absolutely!** As @Bob has already mentioned it's too easy for common file names to be overwritten.

There are also some issues that you might want to cover, for instance not all the allowed chars in Windows are allowed in *nix, and vice versa. A filename may also contain a relative path and could potentially overwrite other non-uploaded files.

Here is the `Upload()` method I wrote for the [phunction PHP framework](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/):

```
function Upload($source, $destination, $chmod = null)
{
    $result = array();
    $destination = self::Path($destination);

    if ((is_dir($destination) === true) && (array_key_exists($source, $_FILES) === true))
    {
        if (count($_FILES[$source], COUNT_RECURSIVE) == 5)
        {
            foreach ($_FILES[$source] as $key => $value)
            {
                $_FILES[$source][$key] = array($value);
            }
        }

        foreach (array_map('basename', $_FILES[$source]['name']) as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$value] = false;

            if ($_FILES[$source]['error'][$key] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
            {
                $file = ph()->Text->Slug($value, '_', '.');

                if (file_exists($destination . $file) === true)
                {
                    $file = substr_replace($file, '_' . md5_file($_FILES[$source]['tmp_name'][$key]), strrpos($value, '.'), 0);
                }

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$source]['tmp_name'][$key], $destination . $file) === true)
                {
                    if (self::Chmod($destination . $file, $chmod) === true)
                    {
                        $result[$value] = $destination . $file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The important parts are:

1. `array_map('basename', ...)`, this makes sure that the file doesn't contain any relative paths.
2. `ph()->Text->Slug()`, this makes sure only `.0-9a-zA-Z` are allowed in the filename, all the other chars are replaced by underscores (`_`)
3. `md5_file()`, this is added to the filename *iff* another file with the same name already exists

I prefer to use the user supplied name since search engines can use that to deliver better results, but if that is not important to you a simple `microtime(true)` or `md5_file()` could simplify things a bit.

Hope this helps! =)

Comment: I hope `if (is_dir($destination) * array_key_exists($source, $_FILES) == 1)` is some sort of inside joke... :-P

Comment: Boolean multiplication is a valid method, but I shudder to think of what'd happen if this was VB, where FALSE is -1. Scary to see this sort of thing either way.

Comment: @Marc "Valid method" as in "it happens to work"? I only see a mild case of code obfuscation with no advantage over `&&`.

Answer (score 5):

The filename is an arbitrary user supplied string. As a general rule, never trust arbitrary user supplied values.

You should never use the user supplied filename as the name to save the file under on the server, always create your own filename. The only thing you *may* want to do with it is to save it as metadata for informational purposes. When outputting that metadata, take the usual precautions like sanitation and escaping.

Answer (score 1):

you also need to check for duplicate names. It's too easy for multiple people to upload an image called 'mycat.jpg', which if uploaded to the same folder would overwrite a previously uploaded file by the same name. You can do this by putting a unique id in the file name (as Prix suggests). Also verify that the file type doesn't just end with an image extension but also is an actual image; you don't want your server acting as a blind host for random files.